# When downloading an app from Google Play, what is the URL the payload is coming from?

Tags: android, networking, ssl, tcpdump

I'm trying to understand the flow when downloading an app from Google Play Store (GPS from now on)
I assume that the phone's GPS app browses to something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms (I'm not related to this app in any way), but my question is what happens when the user hits "install" - where is the binary file served from?
I ran a tcpdump on my phone, but since it's all SSL and I'm not sure what I'm looking for, it's a bit difficult to follow.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

That information is not part of any public knowledge. I suspect that it is not a coincidence that you are having trouble figuring out what the URL is. I imagine it was engineered the way that it was specifically to make it difficult to figure out how it works.

There are no official public APIs for 3rd parties to interact with the Market. So even if you do manage to figure out this URL there is nothing that you are "allowed" to do with it.

**EDIT:** In fact as per the [Android Market Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/about/play-terms.html):

> **Security Features** - You may not attempt to, nor assist, authorise or encourage others to circumvent, disable or defeat any of the security features or components, such as digital rights management software or encryption, that protect any Product or Google Play. If you violate any security feature, you may incur civil or criminal liability.

Now that you know that the url is encrypted with SSL it would be a violation of your agreement with google if attempt to figure it out any further.

Note: I am not a lawyer take my ***opinion*** for what its worth.

Comment: Thanks Tim. To add context, I'm trying to "zero rate" traffic to specific apps within the market. My DPI can zero rate traffic based on URL path, so I can (for example) zero rate traffic to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms but still count traffic to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scan.traceroute&hl=en. However, if these are just the landing pages and the actual binary download happens from a different URL, than this is useless... and I need to know the actual download URL.